# Как изменить язык Woocommerce админки?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

подскажите пожалуйста, как сменить язык админ панели WooCommerce. Вся админка на русском языке, а Woocommerce на EN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вся админка на русском языке, а Woocommerce на EN

У тебя не подтянулся лангпак WC.
Проверяй права на `wp-content/languages`.
В помощь так же https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/